# Conversion of Sizes In Photos

Tags: geometry

Let us suppose that I've taken a photo of a person, the size of this person in the photo is two centimeters

The question is how do I convert his size in the photo into his real size in the real life

Until now I guess that I must subtract the distance between him and the camera and multiply his size by 100, is that right?!

Comment: As vadim mentioned, you need more than just the photo and will most likely need a known reference object within the photo. Anything that you know about the camera and its relation to the scene would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to determine the height of the person without comparing to the height of some reference object also in the same photo.

The same photo can be enlarged, to make the person appear as large or small as desired.    Measuring distances on the printed photograph gives no useful information.

---

If you know the [focal length](http://av.jpn.support.panasonic.com/support/global/cs/dsc/knowhow/knowhow12.html) of your camera lens, and you know the distance of the subject from the camera, and you know the fraction of the viewing angle occupied by the subject, you can estimate the size of the subject, but this will not be accurate enough to distinguish a 5'9" person from a 5'10" person (for instance).